# Best way to configure network devices that have an invalid / non matching network configuration setup?

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming

We're developing some hardware devices in our company that need to communicate through TCP on the network with our application. The devices have some restrictions, such as they do not have a display or a dotmatrix to show any current configuration, such as IP or mac address. Therefore, it is not possible to configure the IP configuration directly on the device.

When they are connected to the network for the first time, there is a high chance, that their current network configuration does not match with the network being connected to.

E.g.

- They are configured to use DHCP and the network does not provide any DHCP.
- They are configured to use a manual IP, such as 192.168.1.1 with a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0, but the network is set up to use 10.X.X.X as IP range with a network mask of 255.0.0.0

We now want to develop a standalone application, that lists all devices being connected to the network and change the IP configuration to a specific one (matching the network needs).

- What needs to be set up on the *device* (running Linux) in order to be capable of the things posted above?
- What needs to be set up on the client side application in order to display the devices and reconfigure them if mismatching? The Application should be a .NET WPF / C# application if possible, admin rights can be aquired if needed.
- Are there any restrictions / scenarios under which we are not able to detect those devices or set up the new network settings?

Answer (score 0):

Leaving out any security issues I would use a udp broadcast to 255.255.255.255 which will been received by any devices. When you put all valid subnets into the payload the client will know that it is wrongly configured and has to answer back as broadcast (since it might be in a different subnet and a unicast is impossible without any valid routing tables)

But please keep in mind that this can open security issues since you will publish on scans all valid subnets which might been very interesting for attackers.

If you know e.g. the Mac addresses of all possible device you may could encrypt the UDP payload which can only been encrypted with the right Mac addresses.

Answer (score 0):

This is what DHCP, BOOTP, RARP are for. Using DHCP and friends to do this sort of thing means a device plonked on a network stands the best possible chance of getting a valid config in the first place.

If you MUST have your own app doing the management of the issue of IP config, then perhaps consider using the DHCP protocol in your management/server app.

If your devices must not speak to a random DHCP server then consider having them either ignore responses that don't have certain attributes in the reply (bit inefficient since it may keep asking and may tie up IPs) or use DHCP on different ports... At least you're not reinventing the wheel then.

Using existing protocols has the benefit that network analysers can understand what's going on too, system admins can debug and make intuitive guesses as to problems, etc.

Comment: I should elaborate: The devices will be shipped to our customers in order to work in their already set up network environment. It can either be plugged in into a DHCP environment (everything should work as expected), but the customer may have set up his own environment *without* having a DHCP server running and each client needs to be configured with a valid ip configuration, hence we can't relay on using DHCP.

Comment: So... presumably you either send someone to the customers site to use this configuration software that configures the device(s) or you send them the software? I still think making the devices do DHCP is best, because you then have to do nothing with the device other than configure it for DHCP... easy... and for the management side (what you called the client side) you could implement a DHCP server (there's code out there, e.g. udhcpd) that responds to your MAC ranges or certain DHCP attributes... It's possible to have 2 DHCP servers on a network even on the standard ports.